# Validate Image Upload is valid passport photo or not through human detecttion using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, file-upload

I have tried for regular image detection using jquery face detection js that works but tried for file upload image detection by previewing the image through reading the uploaded file it returns an error
**Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.**

```js
   <script>
            $(function () {
    
                $("#fp").change(function (e) {
                    var ext = $('#fp').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                    if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
                        $("#fp").val("");
                        alert('invalid extension!');
                    }
                    const file = this.files[0];
                    if (file) {
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (event) {
                            $("#previewImg").attr("src", event.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // $('.face').remove();
                })
                $("#previewImg").faceDetection({
                    complete: function (faces) {
                        if (faces.length > 0) {
                            alert("Valid");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Not Valid");
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
                            $('<div>', {
                                'class': 'face',
                                'css': {
                                    'position': 'absolute',
                                    'left': faces[i].x * faces[i].scaleX + 'px',
                                    'top': faces[i].y * faces[i].scaleY + 'px',
                                    'width': faces[i].width * faces[i].scaleX + 'px',
                                    'height': faces[i].height * faces[i].scaleY + 'px'
                                }
                            })
                                .insertAfter(this);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (code, message) {
                        alert('Error: ' + message);
                    }
                });
    
    
            })
    
        </script>
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
            .picture-container {
                position: relative;
                width: 600px;
                height: auto;
                margin: 20px auto;
                border: 10px solid #fff;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #000;
            }
    
            .picture {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
    
            .face {
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid #FFF;
            }
    
            .row {
                margin: 20px
            }
        </style>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Face Detection - LaravelCode</title>
        <script src="../Content/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.facedetection/jquery.facedetection.min.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="file" id="fp" />
            </div>
    
            <div class="row">
                <img id="previewImg" src="" alt="img">
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried for regular image detection using jquery face detection js that works but tried for file upload image detection by previewing the image through reading the uploaded file it returns an error
**Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.**

Comment: This apparently has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be mindful when tagging.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: that error is because the image src is not set, if you set that to the image path that should resolve the issue

Comment: Hi @Sparky, I'm trying to validate whether the image upload is human or not. There is already a jQuery plugin called face detection js which can detect human images but it works for static images we placed on a web page but. I'm trying to do the same for image upload, while trying in this case it returns  Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0. Is there any possible way to get the image src of an image upload through jQuery? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @PatrickHume . Is there any possible way to get the image src of an image uploaded through jQuery? Thanks in advance

Comment: yes there are several jquery libraries for file upload, I would post the links but I always get downvoted for doing that, so just google "jquery file upload scripts" and pick a library that best suits your needs